# Grails using a get within a g:each

Tags: jquery, grails, get, controller

I'll acknowledge right off that the title is probably not the right reference here so please let me know if I'm using the wrong phrase and I'll correct!

Overview - I have an Form.gsp and corresponding _form.gsp, into which I feed a load of values from an SQL query, which includes the ID from another controller (called Object, multiple object being linked to a form).

During the construction of the table which lists all these objects I need to take the object id and then get it to go off to the Object controller, use the ID to return the objects name and populate the text box with that value.  But I can't work out how to do this, here's what I've tried (cutting out the rubbish of course).

The Objects ID is called object_id and the g:each var is item.  So I've tried to insert it my Object.get(x) as: -

```
value = "${Object.get(item.object_id)}"
```

But this give the error `No signature of method: static java.lang.Object.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.math.BigDecimal) values: [4]`

Incidentally the ID value is 4 that I need to look for...

I've also tried

```
value = "${Object.get(${item.object_id})}"
```

But I get an `Unclosed GSP expression` error.

This is within my _form.gsp

```
<table id="eventList">
        <g:each in="${results}" status = "i" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table id = "sub">
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Object</b></td><td>
                            <g:select style="width:550px;"id="objectID[$i]" name="objectID[$i].id" from="${framework.Object.list(sort:"objDesc")}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${item.object_id}" class="many-to-one"/>

                            <richui:autoComplete name="objectID[$i].id" value = "${Object.get(item.object_id)}" action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'object/searchAJAX')}"    />

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>                                
                </td>       
            </tr>
        </g:each>
    </table>
```

Also worth noting that I do just want it to return and display the objDesc value not the whole entry and am not sure how I tell it to basically say "give me back the objDesc where the ID = item.object_ID.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a workaround for this, as I'm using SQL in my controller to send the info to the gsp I simple added in another JOIN to the statement to go and get the objects description value from the object table before I passed through the details, I can now reference it with an "item.object_description"

However, I'd still like to know if its possible to do the look-up as originally intended so I wont mark this as answered just yet...

Answer (score 0):

The first error you're getting:

> No signature of method: static java.lang.Object.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.math.BigDecimal) values: [4]

Indicates that the `Object.get()` call in your `<richui>` tag isn't actually accessing your domain object; it's just the generic java.lang.Object class.

There's a couple of ways you might work around this.

First, you could just import the domain class into your main Form.gsp, and then _form.gsp should inherit it when you  it:

```
<%@ page import="com.mysite.DomainObject" %>
```

Make sure to change the "com.mysite." portion to match the package name of your domain object. The default package in a grails application is the same as the name of your application. So, your import might look like <%@ page import="myApp.Object" %>

Second (more elaborate) way: in your controller, you could pass the actual domain objects you want to access to the gsp. So, at the end of your controller action, you might have something like:

```
def sqlResults = someService.queryMethod(parameter1, parameter2)
def domainObjects = DomainObject.findAllBy( it.property == parameter3 )
[results: sqlResults, myObjects: domainObjects]
```

Given the way you're iterating through the results object using g:each, you may actually need to map the domain objects to the members of your sqlResults. This method is certainly more elaborate than just importing the domain object to your gsp, though it bears considering. Why run sql statements to get the IDs of your domain object when you can use the Grails frameworks findAll methods?

Side note: If you're actually naming your domain class Object, you might consider refactoring with a more domain-specific name, just to avoid any ambiguity. I imagine you just did that for your post, so that it would be more generic, which is fine, but consider using a class name that isn't already in use at the lowest levels of the language.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  Just to clarify I was stupid enough to call the domain Object (so I have an Object.groovy domain doh!)  When you suggest importing the domain class where would I put this?  In the head of the Edit.gsp that calls the _form.gsp?  If so how should it look given the domain is called Object?  I've tried both as you put it and `<%@ page import="com.mysite.Object" %>` but neither work and cause the page to error

Comment: Also to answer your question about using SQL over the standard findAll method was that I needed to do some joins between different tables.  Probably doable in groovy but I could implement it quicker in SQL at the time...

Comment: Typically I see the page import statement at the very top (even above the head tag) of the parent gsp (Edit.gsp). You might be able to put it in the template (_form.gsp), or elsewhere but I'm not sure the location really matters all that much. Take a look at the error you get when using the page import; what exactly does it say? Did you include the "com.mysite." prefix? You should change that to match the package name that contains your domain object; by default, the package name is the same as your application name.

Comment: Also, if you want to rename your domain class so it isn't just Object.groovy, the Groovy Grails Tool Suite may help with that. If you import your project into GGTS, you can right-click a domain object and select "Refactor > Rename" and it will rename most references. Alternatively, I'm sure greater mortals can do it faster with vim. :)

Totally understand on the SQL thing, and I've been there myself. I'd still encourage you to avoid using Groovy SQL to find your domain objects. This may require you to refactor your domain model, but it will give you the power of convention.

Comment: Ah, sorry yes I did just copy that!   shall give it a try with the proper package name and attempt to engage brain!  Cheers :)